spark sql query returns column has 0 length but non null
I have a spark dataframe for a parquet file. The column is string type.
spark.sql("select col_a, length(col_a) from df where col_a is not null")

+-------------------+---------------------------+
|col_a              |length(col_a)              |
+-------------------+---------------------------+
|                   |                          0|
|                   |                          0|
+-------------------+---------------------------+


This will actually return records that have this column with 0 length but shows as Not Null

Perhaps it is a unicode zero-length space character?

What's your question? [ask]

This question is similar to: Difference between null and empty ("") Java String. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
